# Qt5.12 C++ Как динамически загружать QPIxmap в качестве текстуры в QML 3DScen

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, загрузка

Есть приложение отображающее карту в 2D (`QGraphicScene`) и 3D (QML 3D Scene)
Нужно что бы карта на 3DScene динамически отображала карту с 2D Scene
Код QML, Загрузка происходит при помощи `QQuickImageProvider`, который успешно работает с Image в QML, но `TextureLoader` его никак не воспринимает.
Есть ли какой ни будь более простой способ, если нет, то как решить эту проблему?

```
id: scene3d
Entity {
    Entity {
        id: floor

        components: [
            PlaneMesh {
                width: 10
                height: 10
                mirrored: true
            },
            TexturedMetalRoughMaterial {
                id: material
                baseColor:  TextureLoader {
                    id: textureLoader
                    source: "image://colors/yellow.png"
                    format: Texture.SRGB8_Alpha8
                   generateMipMaps: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: Карта 2D + 3D]